# Is it possible to merge multiple meshes into one object without ruining its textures?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, materials, objects

I'm new to blender and I'm trying to make some custom content for TS4.

I'm using blender 2.7 and I've run into an issue where I've got 200+ meshes for the individual hair strands, ~20 different materials and textures, and I need to merge them all into one object.

I've tried joining all of my meshes, and the textures got mixed up.

Is it possible to merge everything without ruining the textures? I'm lost on where to go from here; any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this problem happens when your two objects have multiple UV maps assigned to them. Make sure you only have one UV map for any objects you're combining.

[image]

Comment: I checked; my meshes all have the same UV map. What else could be causing this?